# multiple file upload and save data in database in yii2

Tags: php, yii2, image-uploading

when i upload multiple files in Yii2, i am getting following error and cannot insert data into database:

> finfo_file(C:\xampp\tmp\phpCACD.tmp): failed to open stream: No such
>   file or directory

**controller file:**

```
public function actionGallery($id)
    {
        $model = new Gallery();
        if (Yii::$app->request->post()) {
            $model->imageFiles = UploadedFile::getInstances($model,'imageFiles');    
            foreach ($model->imageFiles as $file) {
                $imageName = Yii::$app->security->generateRandomString();
                $model->added_date = date('Y-m-d');
                $model->emp_id = $id;
                $file->saveAs('uploads/emp/' . $imageName . '.' . $file->extension);
                $originalFile = EMP_PROFILE_ORIGINAL.$imageName.'.'.$file->extension;
                $thumbFile = EMP_PROFILE_THUMB.$imageName.'.'.$file->extension;
                Image::thumbnail($originalFile, 200, 200)->save($thumbFile, ['quality' => 80]);
                $model->save();
            }
        }
        return $this->render('gallery', [
            'gal' => $model
            ]);
    }
```

**view file:**

```
<?php
use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;
use yii\grid\GridView;
?>

<div class="posts-form">
    <div class="wrapper-md">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-8">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-body">

                        <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['options' => ['enctype' => 'multipart/form-data']]); ?>
                        <?= $form->field($gal, 'imageFiles[]')->fileInput(['multiple' => true, 'accept' => 'image/*']) ?>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <button class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
                            <a class="btn btn-default" href="<?=\Yii::$app->urlManager->createUrl('post')?>">Cancel</a>
                        </div>
                        <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

but i am getting above error. I cannot find the solution for this.

Comment: I think `$model = new Gallery();` should be inside `foreach() loop`

Answer (score 2):

first, in model you must have 2 variable that will save the images and the name of it.

```
`
* @property string $image_name
*/
class Gallery extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    **public $fileImage=[];**
    public static function tableName(){
`
```

in this case I use $image_name that is one of my model column, and $fileImage, $fileImage is an array that will be used to upload the image,

:)

then in controller

```
$model = new Gallery(); // this variable is only used to check if everything is valid
if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
    $model->fileImage = UploadedFile::getInstances($model,'fileImage');
    $a=0;
    foreach ($model->fileImage as $file) {
        $a++;
        $model1 = new Gallery();
        $file->saveAs("images/test".$a.".".$file->extension);
        $model1->image_url="images/test.".$a.".".$file->extension;
        $model1->image_name = "".$a;

        $model1->save();
    }

    return $this->redirect(['index']);
} else {
    return $this->render('create', [
        'model' => $model,
    ]);
}
```

I think thats all. . .

Comment: i will try and back to you

Comment: images are going to the folder but not in db

Comment: the image name save in $model1->image_url,,,,
image_url is a field in my database that used to save the name of that files

Comment: sorry, I have no internet access yesterday :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
$sql = 'INSERT INTO `table`(`id`, `col1`, `col2`, `path`) VALUES (Null,"'.($model2->col1).'","'.($model2->col2).'","'.($model2->path).'")';
                $command = \Yii::$app->db->createCommand($sql);
                $command->execute();
```

instead of $model->save();

I made an example,
so the whole code in controller would be:

```
public function actionCreate()
    {
        $model = new Planet();

        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) ) {

             $model->file = UploadedFile::getInstances($model, 'file');
            foreach ($model->file as $file) {

            $model2 = new Planet();

            $model2->load(Yii::$app->request->post());
             $model2->path='uploads/' . $file;

            $sql = 'INSERT INTO `planet`(`id`, `name`, `s_id`, `path`) VALUES (Null,"'.($model2->name).'","'.($model2->s_id).'","'.($model2->path).'")';
            $command = \Yii::$app->db->createCommand($sql);
            $command->execute();
                $file->saveAs('uploads/' . $file->baseName . '.' . $file->extension);

            }
                  return $this->render('view', [
                    'model' => $model,
                    ]);

        } else {
            return $this->render('create', [
                'model' => $model,
            ]);
        }
    }
```

It works for me.

**edit**: also you can use $model2->save(false); It worked in my case.

Comment: this is the temporary solution

Answer (score 0):

Call `$model->save()`

before

```
$model->file->saveAs();
```

I was having the exact same problem

Comment: already tried it but not working.. it is in foreach loop.. i want to save name of image into database also

Answer (score -1):

*I think you forget to create uploads and emp folder or maybe you use wrong  folder name, please check your folder name...

*If you want to save the name of that file, you should use different variable (two variable) that will be used to save the images and the name of that images,

Comment: folder name is right. problem is that first image is uploaded into the folder but not going to save the imagename in database. and it raise the error when trying to upload second image.

Comment: may I see your code in the form?
in $model->imageFiles = UploadedFile::getInstances($model,'imageFiles'); What is the ImageFiles data-types??, 
is $file->saveAs('uploads/emp/' . $imageName . '.' . $file->extension); work? because you use $file that never declare before,

you said that you want to save multiple image name in your model, is the name will be saved in different row? if yes, you should declare $model = new Gallery();

Comment: is the name of the file will save in different row?
use this inside your foreach if yes
$model = new Gallery();
are you have another variable in model that will used to save the name of the image? because I think you need that